# Updating Canvas all at the same time

Tags: html5-canvas

I have an asp.net website.
I have 4 canvas controls. 
I am uploading jpegs from my client desktop app from 4 different cameras.
1 canvas control per camera.

All works well.

Now, I just use 1 camera.  This camera is of a higher resolution.
I still split this larger image into 4 parts (in the client).
I then upload all 4 parts and update each canvas element as before.

Now, when there is motion on the camera there is a 'shimmering' of movement because each image part updates sequentially.

I have thought about hiding a canvas control and displaying when all 4 parts are updated but is this the best solution for the canvas control?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps don't split the image & use 1 larger canvas when displaying the larger image?

Comment: @markE Hi Mark, I am considering this. I have now switched to using 1 large canvas and using putImageData using x,y positioning. I am still putting it together even as I type. But, the images coming in have to be split in 4 and joined as 1 to avoid 'shimmering'.  The image is split into 4 to reduce the amount of bytes I upload via my wcf at any one time. I have found when uploading large byte arrays it 'drags' the flow of uploads and if I split them the FPS stays high. I have no proof of this as to why it was just an observation.

Comment: It's simpler (+better performance) to use drawImage to "stitch together" your 4 images.

Comment: @markE Hi again.  I was getting the byte array calling a generic handler. From there I would load the bytes into a jpeg.js class. I then used the copyToImageData from this JS class to put into my ctx1.getImageData(0,0,360,288) object, after which i used putImageData from my canvas object. Because I am dealing directly with a jpeg byte object I do not think I cam use drawImage. Maybe wrong lol.

Comment: So is the image being captured at the same location where it's being drawn on a canvas--no server involved?  Can your camera(s) deliver data in image format rather than byte arrays?  I ask because getImageData+putImageData is a performance killer and might be the source of the delay causing your shimmering.

Comment: Hi, the image is captured on my desktop PC app. It then uses wcf to upload a byte array to my server.  The byte array is then read by a generic call from client web app.  The 'shimmering' is cause by uploading and updating the image on the client browser sequentially- 1 image at a time (four times) to make a whole image. I am now looking at using a hidden canvas control and then updating the visible canvas when all 4 parts have finished uploading. I shall see where that takes me :)